Hebrew language and \makeindex incompatibility/glitch
NOTE: This issue occurs only with pdflatex; to avoid completely, use a compiler such as luatex instead.
I'm using TeXstudio to typeset public domain books pulled off Project Gutenberg.
It's kind of a hobby project to teach me, among other things, how to use LaTeX, how to use RegEx, how to parse & convert document formats (i.e. HTML > TeX), and also as a bit of a design exercise (good typesetting, font choice, cover design, etc.). I've already used the LaTeX skills for report generation.
Here's the problem:
When I create an index, the \makeindex script generates index entries that look like this:
\indexentry{Yeomans, Robert}{\@@number {10}}

The workaround is to do a bulk replace on the .IDX file, recompile the document and then (because the document contains \makeindex), tell the app to keep the open IDX file instead of overwriting it.
The result is an index file that's usable, but this is a lot of awkward steps to go through.
The problem occurs when the Hebrew language package is used. Changing the babel package from:
\usepackage[russian, hebrew, greek.polutoniko, english]{babel}

to
\usepackage[russian, greek.polutoniko, english]{babel}

results in properly formatted IDX files.
Now, granted, the easy fix is to just leave the Hebrew package out, except when it's needed. The problem is that I'd like a universal fix here, one that works regardless of whether there's a need for Hebrew typeset in the doc.
There is a 14 year old thread on the Latex.org forums about the apparent Hebrew/imakeidx incompatibilities, but there is no solution offered, just the idea that you should switch language packages.
https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10620
Here's a MWE -- swap hebrew in/out of the babel package specs and it will either work or not.
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
% Packages %
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[hebrew, english]{babel}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter{In which a MWE is displayed}
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dolor diam, vehicula non 
convallis efficitur, laoreet sit amet nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et 
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In feugiat nulla augue, malesuada semper leo 
ullamcorper eget. Pellentesque nec rutrum ex. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} pharetra nisl sed mauris 
gravida ultricies. Sed consectetur eu purus quis pellentesque. Aenean at ipsum dolor.
\par
Nullam suscipit mauris at condimentum placerat. Sed volutpat eros in lectus elementum, in maximus 
turpis consectetur. Quisque sagittis, diam in mollis cursus, ipsum tellus iaculis velit, at 
congue erat odio in odio. Donec orci justo, bibendum nec tortor non, auctor pretium massa. 
Phasellus non molestie tortor. Nulla facilisi. Fusce\index{Fusce} placerat molestie turpis vel 
egestas. Quisque tempus venenatis nulla id auctor. Vestibulum pharetra, massa vitae congue 
posuere, nibh urna luctus mauris, sed auctor quam dolor quis tortor. Vivamus a varius massa, et 
dictum diam. Morbi tincidunt lorem sit amet consectetur\index{consectetur} congue. Etiam 
fermentum dui eros, commodo condimentum lectus laoreet lacinia.

\printindex
\end{document}  


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Are the Hebrew texts just a few words or simple paragraphs (letters and punctuation)?

@JavierBezos, some documents don't have any Hebrew at all. However, this is a script with an interface, and to keep the interface as simple as possible (there are already over 50 parameters to set), I want to be able to just accept Hebrew w/o asking if it's present.

You will need to set up a font for Hebrew, but I expect you know that already. @JavierBezos I'm guessing the documents may include ones written in Hebrew or with extended passages, so I figured it might be best not to rely on, say, \foreignlanguage. Is there a better solution to get indexing working with the ldf?

I was preparing an answer based on my previous question, which is relevant. @RichJensen, please, can you confirm the Hebrew texts are short?

@JavierBezos, they would be, in general. The spur to include Hebrew, initially, was a snippet in Moby Dick.

Based on the example for Swedish and Hebrew in Babel's docs and tested with pdfLaTeX and luaLaTeX.
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
% Packages %
\usepackage{imakeidx}
% page 25 of babel manual mod from swedish
% note english=american
\usepackage[english,bidi=default]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter{In which a MWE is displayed}
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dolor diam, vehicula non 
convallis efficitur, laoreet sit amet nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et 
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In feugiat nulla augue, malesuada semper leo 
ullamcorper eget. Pellentesque nec rutrum ex. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} pharetra nisl sed mauris 
gravida ultricies. Sed consectetur eu purus quis pellentesque. Aenean at ipsum dolor.
\par
Nullam suscipit mauris at condimentum placerat. Sed volutpat eros in lectus elementum, in maximus 
turpis consectetur. Quisque sagittis, diam in mollis cursus, ipsum tellus iaculis velit, at 
congue erat odio in odio. Donec orci justo, bibendum nec tortor non, auctor pretium massa. 
Phasellus non molestie tortor. Nulla facilisi. Fusce\index{Fusce} placerat molestie turpis vel 
egestas. Quisque tempus venenatis nulla id auctor. Vestibulum pharetra, massa vitae congue 
posuere, nibh urna luctus mauris, sed auctor quam dolor quis tortor. Vivamus a varius massa, et 
dictum diam. Morbi tincidunt lorem sit amet consectetur\index{consectetur} congue. Etiam 
fermentum dui eros, commodo condimentum lectus laoreet lacinia.

\printindex
\end{document} 


I can confirm that this resolves the issue!

Strongly recommended: use luatex (or xetex, but I much prefer the former).
Here the problem is bidi scripts require a good deal of patching, and the hebrew style assumes they are always necessary. But you can resort to the alternative method provided by babel, based on descriptive ini locale files.
For short texts in ‘foreign’ languages there is no need to declare them explicitly, because they can be loaded on the fly if required. This mechanism was devised mainly (but not exclusively) for auto-generated documents, which, I think, might be your case. Sadly, with pdflatex you still need loading the encodings in the preamble (loading them in the middle of the document is problematic).
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[T2A, NHE8, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, bidi=default]{babel}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter{In which a MWE is displayed}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
dolor diam, vehicula non convallis efficitur, laoreet sit amet nisi.

\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
מתן גם החול שנורו אינטרנט, ויש למנוע קודמות מיוחדים או, רבה שיתופית
פילוסופיה אם. מתן גם שתפו מיזמי אספרנטו. שתפו אחרונים לרפובליקה ויש או,
רביעי האנציקלופדיה כתב של, אל זאת אנגלית אירועים. 
\end{otherlanguage}

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} pharetra nisl sed
mauris gravida ultricies.

\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, дебет аеяуе делецтус еу нам. Ут сумо
фастидии дигниссим нец, хас ин дицо оцурререт абхорреант, сцрипта
доценди цоммуне ид мел. Вел ин феугиат адолесценс. 
\end{otherlanguage}

Morbi tincidunt lorem sit amet consectetur\index{consectetur} congue.
Etiam fermentum dui eros, commodo condimentum lectus laoreet lacinia.

\printindex
\end{document}  


The .idx file is:
\indexentry{Phasellus}{1}
\indexentry{consectetur}{1}

With lualatex you have to declare the fonts, and \babelfont was devised having in mind auto-generated documents, too, so that the font is not loaded except if required (in other words, you can declare as many fonts as you want, just in case). Here an example (note the font metrics in luatex are slightly different):
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[english, bidi=default]{babel}
\babelfont[hebrew, russian]{rm}{NewComputerModern10}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter{In which a MWE is displayed}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
dolor diam, vehicula non convallis efficitur, laoreet sit amet nisi.

\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
מתן גם החול שנורו אינטרנט, ויש למנוע קודמות מיוחדים או, רבה שיתופית
פילוסופיה אם. מתן גם שתפו מיזמי אספרנטו. שתפו אחרונים לרפובליקה ויש או,
רביעי האנציקלופדיה כתב של, אל זאת אנגלית אירועים. 
\end{otherlanguage}

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus\index{Phasellus} pharetra nisl sed
mauris gravida ultricies.

\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, дебет аеяуе делецтус еу нам. Ут сумо
фастидии дигниссим нец, хас ин дицо оцурререт абхорреант, сцрипта
доценди цоммуне ид мел. Вел ин феугиат адолесценс. 
\end{otherlanguage}

Morbi tincidunt lorem sit amet consectetur\index{consectetur} congue.
Etiam fermentum dui eros, commodo condimentum lectus laoreet lacinia.

\printindex
\end{document}  



Y'know, this is a project that I sat on for a couple years, and as soon as you mentioned luatex, I recalled switching to that compiler from pdflatex when I was last working on the project (and since I've formatted/reloaded TeXStudio multiple times, the default compiler has reverted to PDFlates). I'm going to edit the question to show the value of your answer as well.
